# Является ли перевод в байт-код в python построчным?

Tags: python, runtime, перевод

Имеется код:

```
try:
    def f():
        print('hi')
        print('bye) # здесь намеренно пропущен закрывающий апостроф
except:
    pass
          
f()
```

Целью эксперимента было: выяснить, что произойдёт при вызове функции `f`, построчное определение (def) которой в run-time провалилось. Предполагалось, что определение (def) как оператор провалилось, поэтому объект функции и ссылка `f` на него не создадутся в глобальной области видимости модуля. Поэтому предполагалось, что вызов `f()` приведёт к возбуждению исключения NameError.

В действительности оказалось, что при запуске выходит SyntaxError, и строка 'hi' не печатается. Думаю, что то ли блок `try` не ловит исключение, то ли bite-code всего модуля не смог создаться, а потому не выполнился его запуск в принципе, и оператор `def` даже не начинал работу (собственно как и последующий оператор вызова `f()`).

**Вопрос**: Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, почему до вызова `f()` дело не дошло. Возможно одно из моих предположений выше верно, тогда хотелось бы увидеть ссылки на документацию, подробно объясняющие происходящее.

Comment: Байт-код создаётся компилятором. У нормального компилятора все синтаксические ошибки должны устраняться до формирования кода (и вы как-то очень странно слово байт-код на английском пишете, надо бы вообще английского поменьше в русскоязычных текстах).

Comment: Компилятор работает по фазам. Первая фаза - синтаксический разбор текста целиком файла с исходным кодом. Если разбор закончился ошибкой в любом месте, далее компиляция не пойдёт и исполнимый код не будет создан и исполнен.

Comment: Кроме всего прочего, чтобы сработал блок `try-except` он должен обработаться интерпретатором, а у вас `except` не смог быть интерпретирован из-за не закрытой выше кавычки, поэтому тут без толку надеяться на то, что исключение будет поймано в любом случае, один только `try` без `except` - это уже синтаксическая ошибка, если бы её и можно было вдруг поймать, то где-то выше по стеку, другим `try-except`. Но так то это всё умозрительно и всё-равно не сработает, см. ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала исходник проходит фазу токенизации. Потом из токенов строится AST. Потом компилятор транслирует AST в байткод. Полученный байткод выполняет PVM. Перехват исключений, очевидно, может работать только в процессе выполнения байткода виртуальной машиной, на предыдущих этапах самого механизма исключений ещё не существует, поэтому SyntaxError перехватить нельзя. Конечно, если исключить варианты с парсингом в рантайме, типа выполнения инструкции `eval`.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, Сергей! Помню, Вы и по Java мне очень много помогали. Проработал похожий пример с использованием exec(), и смог сделать шаг в понимании динамической схемы создания функций в python. Ещё раз спасибо